# Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <480, 75>, Has: <454, 90>

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

I'm trying to show adMobs in my android app. But in logCat it gives me the following

```
 Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <480, 75>, Has: <454, 90>
```

This is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/adUnitId"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/tipList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttons"
    android:divider="#C0C0C0"
    android:dividerHeight="2px"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define minWidth/minHeight to the required 480/75?

Comment: Could you show me how, please?

Comment: You could have searched for "minWidth Android" to find, oh what a surprise: `android:minWidth`... Guess why I wrote `minWidth` instead of `minimal width`. Please just take a step back and try to understand what you read...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you don't have the minimum space height/width (width in your case) for showing the ad.

**Edit:**

Try setting `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for the LinearLayout.

Answer (score 4):

set parent item:

**android:paddingLeft="0dp"**

**android:paddingRight="0dp"**

i solved like that.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely not solvable for all devices. Here's what I found out when it happened on one of my test devices.

You're requesting BANNER sized ads (ads:adSize="BANNER"), which is defined as 320x50, these are however dp, not pixels. ([AdMob banner sizes](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/intermediate))

I was trying to show a BANNER sized ad on a Sony ARC in portrait mode. The ARC has 480 x 854 pixels and I thought a 320x50 banner should be just fine, but I got

```
Needs 480x75 pixels, but only has 452x826 pixels.
```

What happened was: 
The Arc has a pixel density of ~233 dpi.
So the 320dp of the banner became according to

```
pixels = dp * (dpi / 160)
```

= approximately 466 pixels.

Not sure why it wanted 480, but maybe there's a frame and they might use a slightly different number for the density.

Check also [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/sFRnGLKHrUI) on Google Groups by Eric Leichtenschlag.

Answer (score 0):

set android:layout_height="0dip" and android:layout_weight="1" for your listView and it will takes as much size as it can but it will give space needed to display adView. Something like this

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/tipList"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_below="@+id/buttons"
android:divider="#C0C0C0"
android:dividerHeight="2px"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
```

Answer (score 0):

My solvation was setting the width of the AdView as fixed "360db". In the case of anothers needs.